# ASP .NET MVC Freezes Visual Studio during new Project Creation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2008

I'm using VS 2008 with SP1, on WinXP Pro, and I successfully installed the MVC package from Microsoft. I start a new project, select the MVC web project type, and give it a name and folder. When I press go it hangs forever.

The "ProjectName" folder is created, but nothing else is there.

I can create and open all my other projects without any issues.

Any ideas what's causing this issue? I can't try the MVC framework if I can't create a project!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Process Monitor & Process Explorer, you can probably find out what VS is waiting for.

PM: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx

PE: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx

Answer (score 0):

[I had a similar issue:](http://blog.priester.net/2009/04/16/nerd-dinner-aspnet-mvc-sample-app-crashing-visual-studio-2008/) Instead of uninstalling Visual Studio add-ons I tried the fix.

I found this blog post form the VS team:
http://blogs.msdn.com/webdevtools/archive/2009/03/03/hotfix-available-for-asp-net-mvc-crashes-with-azure-power-commands-resharper.aspx

that points to a fix:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?DownloadID=16827&wa=wsignin1.0

It Worked!

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have specified that I am using Windows XP Pro, so the downloads you linked to don't apply, unfortunately.

Comment: I am also using Windows XP Pro. I used NDP20SP2-KB963676-x86.exe and it worked like a champ.

Comment: Well, I gave it a shot, but unfortunately there's no change. I think the issues are different -- your issue seemed to have been opening and adding certain types of files to an existing project. In this case, I can't even create the MVC project to begin with, it freezes right before it generates the new files.

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to [ASP.NET MVC 2 Preview 2](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=d3f06bb9-5f5f-4f46-91e9-813b3fce2db1&displaylang=en).